# Getting timezone for JavaScript and PHP all mixed up

Tags: php, javascript, timezone, timestamp, utc

I'm trying to synchronize the timezone between a PHP script and some JavaScript code.

I want a PHP function that returns a timestamp in UTC. Does [gmmktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) do that?

On the JavaScript side, I have:

```
var real_date = new Date();
real_date    -= real_date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
real_date    /= 1000;
```

Does this convert the timestamp to UTC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## PHP

Just [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) will do what you want. If you want an arbitrary timestamp, instead of the current time, then `gmmktime` will do that, yes.

> Returns the current time measured in
>   the number of seconds since the Unix
>   Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

## Javascript

You can use the `.UTC()` method of a Date object to get # of milliseconds in UTC. However, your current solution should also work, if you're starting with a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks. So just to confirm... time() in PHP is timezone-independent?

Comment: Yes. `time()` always returns UTC timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

For the Javascript question [UTC](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp)

Comment: actually gmdate returns the Greenwich Mean Time, I was wrong, I'll edit it.

Comment: FWIW, unless you're concerned about accuracy down to fractional seconds (and if you are, you probably aren't using PHP), GMT and UTC should be equivalent.